# HQL Hibernate nested joins

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have the following referential constraints setup so that, in:

```
Table A, Table B, Table C

A.bid = B.id
B.cid = c.id
```

I need to run a query that retrieves a Table A object with following filters:

```
A.someCol = 'someVal' and C.someCol='someVal'
```

So far I have been able to come up with this. This returns a TableAObj but TableCObj is null:

```
select new TableAObj(TableBObj,TableCObj)
from TableAObj as tao 
left join tao.TableBObj as tbo 
left join tbo.TableCObj as tco 
where tao.someCol = ? and tco.someCol = ?
```

What is my query missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's the query:

```
select from TableAObj where TableAOb.someCol = ? 
and TableAObj.TableBObj.TableCObj.someCol = ?
```

Didn't need the overloaded constructor or the explicit joins.